# Passing boolean parameter to method

Tags: java, parameters, boolean, parameter-passing

When I try passing a boolean parameter which is declared locally in another method  the compiler delivers the the error:

> Error:(40, 71) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable frei
>   location: class flugVerein

the method that gets the boolean variable passed:

```
public static void verfügbar(int[] flugAnzahl, String[] vorname, String[] bezeichnung, int[] zeit, boolean frei)
```

where the variable is declared:

```
public static void ganzeTag(int[] zeit, String[] vorname, String[] nachname, String[] bezeichnung) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Geben Sie die Bezeichnung des Fluges ein: ");
    String eingabe = sc.nextLine();
    boolean frei = false;
```

the method call in the main method:

```
verfügbar(flugAnzahl, vorname, bezeichnung, zeit, frei);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `frei` variable since you are in a different method. It was declared in the `ganzeTag` method, but you are trying to access it in the `main` method. There are a few things you can do. The easiest way in my opinion is to make it a field.

```
private static boolean frei;
```

Then in the `ganzeTag` method:

```
public static void ganzeTag(int[] zeit, String[] vorname, String[] nachname, String[] bezeichnung) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Geben Sie die Bezeichnung des Fluges ein: ");
    String eingabe = sc.nextLine();
    frei = false; // don't put the boolean.
```

Actually, you don't even need that line, because the default value for the boolean field is false.

```
public static void ganzeTag(int[] zeit, String[] vorname, String[] nachname, String[] bezeichnung) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Geben Sie die Bezeichnung des Fluges ein: ");
    String eingabe = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jwan I think you're referring to a local variable.